# How to update the colorbar of a heatmap inside the GUI pyqt?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt, pyqt5, seaborn

i am having problems to update a GUI with a heatmpan and color bar, the problem is that i can update the heatmap well but in each update it is added a new color bar. 
My problem is especifically with the colors bars, i tried to remove the color bar, but, if i removed it desappear from the program and i need it. The problem can be saw in the attached image.

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    send_fig = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.main_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.fig = Figure()
        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.im=self.ax.images 

        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.fig)

        self.canvas.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, 
                                  QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.canvas.updateGeometry()

        self.dropdown1 = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        self.dropdown1.addItems(["Número de puntos", "Número de transacciones", "Valor promedio de las tx"])
        self.dropdown1.setCurrentIndex(2)

        self.dropdown1.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.update)

        #self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel("A plot:")

        self.layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.main_widget)
        self.layout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel("Selecciona una categoría"))
        self.layout.addWidget(self.dropdown1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.canvas)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.main_widget)
        self.show()
        self.update()

    def update(self):


        self.ax.clear()

        datosHeatMap = pd.read_csv(r"\file.csv")

        df = pd.DataFrame(datosHeatMap, columns =["id_comercio","HoraNumero","Hora","DiaNum","Día","Puntos","Transacciones","Clientes","Valor","Cargas","Redenciones"])
        puntos = []
        puntos.append(df.pivot("HoraNumero","DiaNum","Puntos").fillna(0).astype(float))
        puntos.append(df.pivot("HoraNumero","DiaNum","Transacciones").fillna(0).astype(float))
        puntos.append(df.pivot("HoraNumero","DiaNum","Valor").fillna(0).astype(float))

        dias=[]

        numDia = {0:"Lunes",1:"Martes",2:"Miercoles",3:"Jueves",4:"Viernes",5:"Sabado",6:"Domingo",}

        dias.append(list(puntos[0].columns))
        dias.append(list(puntos[1].columns))
        dias.append(list(puntos[2].columns))

        cat1_index = self.dropdown1.currentIndex()
        cat1_text = self.dropdown1.currentText()


        self.ax.set_title(cat1_text)

        sns.heatmap(puntos[cat1_index],cmap="YlGnBu",vmin=puntos[cat1_index].values.min(),vmax=puntos[cat1_index].values.max(),center=np.median(puntos[cat1_index].values), ax= self.ax)
        self.ax.collections[-1].colorbar.update_normal(self.ax)
        #this is a list of all images that have been plotted
        #self.ax.collections[-1].colorbar.set_clim(puntos[cat1_index].values.min(),puntos[cat1_index].values.max())
        self.ax.set_xticklabels(list(map(numDia.get, dias[cat1_index])))
        self.fig.canvas.draw_idle()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Color bars are added in each update

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each call to `sns.heatmap` creates a new colorbar.

You should create a specific Axes to be used for the colorbar in your init function. I'm using GridSpec here to create an axis that's 10x thinner than the main axes. There are plenty of other ways to create this axes, just do a search here on SO.

```
def __init__(self):
    (...)
    self.fig = Figure()
    gs00 = matplotlib.gridspec.GridSpec(1, 2, width_ratios=[10,1])
    self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(gs00[0])
    self.cax = self.fig.add_subplot(gs00[1])
    (...)
```

then pass the reference to this object to `sns.heatmap`:

```
def update(self):
    (...)
    sns.heatmap(..., ax=self.ax, cbar_ax=self.cax)
    (...)
```